# How can I pack/unpack Matlab workspace data into a binary file?

Tags: matlab, binaryfiles

I want to pack some data from the Matlab workspace into a binary file and then be able to recover that data back into the workspace at some later time. (The data forms part of the header of a telemetry data log. It's useful to have the data that generated the telemetry directly within the file.)

I am aware that the `load` and `save` commands will do exactly this, but I think my condition is unique. Once I save the workspace data to the file, I have another program (written in C) that opens the file and appends telemetry data to the file. I don't think `load` and `save` will handle this.

I've partially solved the problem using the [`cstruct`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4048-cstruct) tool found on the Mathworks File Exchange to pack data into a blob and write it to the file using `fwrite`. The caveat with this approach is that `cstruct` must be aware of the packing format when it unpacks. The format of the data has changed and is likely to change again so it would be nice to remove this requirement.

Ideally, I would like to write a byte count X to the file header followed by a binary blob (of size X) containing the data in MAT format, followed by the variably-sized blob of telemetry data. When I want to unpack the data I read the X bytes of data, interpret it as a MAT file and it magically appears in the workspace.

Is there a way of packing workspace variables to a binary blob and then unpacking them without prior knowledge of their structure, **but the binary data is stored as part of a larger file**?

*Edit: Added clarification that I don't think `load` and `save` are what I need.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab's [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command is exactly what you want. To load the variables again, use [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

**Update:** Now I see what you're trying to do. My best idea is to create a .mat file using `save`, then embed that file in your custom binary file (just copy the bytes). To recover the Matlab data, extract those bytes to create a new .mat file, then use `load`. This method is nice because you do minimal binary formatting and it will handle *any* Matlab data.

Bonus tip: A good place for the temporary .mat files is in the [tempdir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempdir.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, shoelzer. I think it wasn't clear from my original wording, but I would like the packed data to be embedded within a larger binary file. I don't think `save` and `load` do this. I've edited my question to make this tidbit a bit clearer.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I had in mind, though I was hoping for a solution without the temp files.

Comment: @RyanEdwards I don't know of any way around the temp files. I look at them as a small price to pay for such a simple solution.